# Change input with an input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to change the color and text of an input by clicking on a different input?.

In short it is: when clicking ferrari by css raises change the background-color to red What I would like was to also change the word Available to Unavailable. is it possible to do this?

here I make the change of the color onclick.

```
    input{
      display: none
    }
    input:checked+label>.choices {
      background-color: red !important;

    }
```

In the other block I have the following Script

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function insereInput() {
  if ( document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML == 'Disponivel' ) {
   
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = '<marquee>Em Serviço</marquee>';
    
    document.getElementById('inputprogram').innerHTML = '<marquee>Em Serviço</marquee>';
  } else {
  
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'Disponivel';
    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'Disponivel';
  }
}
</script>
```

which changes the status by clicking between "Available" and "In service".

My short code is:

```
<td>
<div class="btn-wrap">
<input type="checkbox" id="veiculos1"  /><label for="veiculos1"><div class="choices">FERRARI</div></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="filtro"  /><label for="filtro1"><div class="choices3"><span id="btn" onclick="insereInput()">Disponivel</span></div></label>
</div>
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: you have.reason I explained poorly. it's not really a click and an insertinput. my question is whether in the same way as with:
```
  input{
       display: none
     }
     input:checked+label>.choices {
       background-color: red !important;

     }
```
Is there any way that besides changing the background color I can change the text of my input at the same time:
```
<input type="checkbox" id="filter" /><label for="filter1"><div class="choices3"><span id="btn" onclick="insertInput()">Available</span> </div></label>
</div>
``` to "Indisponivel"

Answer (score -1):

```
   
<script>
        function mytest() {
            var x = document.getElementById("btn");
              
            if (x.innerHTML === "Disponivel") {
                x.innerHTML = "Em Serviço";
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Disponivel";
            }
        }
    </script>
```